# How to port pgm_read_byte macro (AVR) to 8051

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, avr, 8051

**Im tring to port driver from AVR to 8051.
Does anyone know how to port pgm_read_byte this macro?**

```
#define   pgm_read_byte(address_short) pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)
...
#define   pgm_read_byte_near(address_short)   __LPM((uint16_t)(address_short))
...
#define   __LPM(addr)                         __LPM_enhanced__(addr)
...
#define __LPM_enhanced__(addr)  \
(__extension__({                \
uint16_t __addr16 = (uint16_t)(addr); \
uint8_t __result;           \
__asm__                     \
(                           \
    "lpm %0, Z" "\n\t"      \
    : "=r" (__result)       \
    : "z" (__addr16)        \
);                          \
__result;                   \
}))
```

Comment: Which 8051 compiler are you targeting? Also, do you have a sample use of this macro, along with how the data they want to read is declared?

Comment: Hi, Jester, I use IAR.   Sample: pixels = pgm_read_byte_near(data + b - 1) & 0xaa;   Also, does  __result; in #define __LPM_enhanced__(addr) means return __result?

Answer (score 0):

What compiler?  What brand of 8051?

In Keil C51 you just need to tag the memory as `code` and you can read from program memory just fine.  I think the works with casting, so you could try `(*(code uint8_t *)(address_short))`.

On some chips, the memory and code space are actually in one flat 16 bit address space, making it possible to use the wrong instructions (`MOVC` vs `MOVX`) to access memory successfully.  Those chips can usually execute out of RAM as well.